# Too many redirects error when redirecting in Apache2

Tags: redirect, apache2

I'm using Apache2 (2.4.46) and a simple `Redirect`, and I'm getting the `Too many redirects` error.

What I want:
When traffic comes to `https://www.example.com/` I want to redirect it to `https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST`

I'm using a simple redirect in httpd.conf, in my VirtualHost definition, that says:
Redirect / /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

When I test w/ curl, I see this (edited to obscure real host names):

[oracle@my-server ~]$ ./redirects.sh https://www.example.com

---

### https://www.example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

<....much repetition deleted....>

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
-> Location: https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POSTShibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

So, I understand what's happening, but I have no idea how to prevent it.  I want the `Redirect` to work once, and then terminate.

Help?

Comment: What if it comes at some other url like `/abc`? what needs to happen then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below redirect which is only done for root url `/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST/ [R=302]
```

Initially you should configure `R=302`, when it works you can change it to `R=301` so that the browser will cache the redirect